# Disfunctioning songs on Apple music

Tags: itunes, music, apple-music

Some songs in apple music can't be played. It is very weird cause in the start I could listen to these songs, and then suddenly they became unable to play. They just turned grey and it isn't possible to play them. It is very frustrating and I know that it hasn't something to do with my internet connection. It is like this at both my macbook and my iPhone. Have anyone else experienced this? And does anyone know if there is a way of fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes songs are removed from Apple Music at the request of the artist/ publisher.

If you do *Get Info* on a track you have a problem with, go to the *File* tab and see what it says for iCloud Status.

If it says *No Longer Available* then it is as I have described above and is shown in the screenshot I have attached.

[image]